# extract parent folder and filename from copied windowspath with pathlib has rpoblems wit \N and \s

Tags: python, pathlib

I have tried to translate a copied windowspath and extract a filename and parent folder with pathlib/Path.

code like this

```
#import file selected_products
windows_file_path = "D:\Lokale schijf\NAME\datafiles\BRANDS\VDV\sw_imports\badmode voororder narta CAF-tenedos JAZ.csv"
file_name = Path(windows_file_path).name
source_parent_folder = Path(windows_file_path).parent
print(source_parent_folder)
print(file_name)
```

result

```
 File "C:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6556/1713150910.py", line 2
    windows_file_path = "D:\Lokale schijf\NAME\datafiles\BRANDS\VDV\sw_imports\badmode voororder narta CAF-tenedos JAZ.csv"
                                                                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 16-17: malformed \N character escape
```

how can I avoid these \N and \s problems

Comment: does `windows_file_path = r"D:\Lokale schijf\NAME\..."` work?

Comment: it does. Use raw string works fine